# Code for extracting all rows pretaining to a specific value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm new to data science and trying to do some data wrangling with python 2.7 in iPython notebook. A tutorial I was following for my first project asked me to replace all NaN intputs with Y or N. But I'd like to consider another approach where I can 1st look at all the rows with NaN inputs for a specific column so that I can utilize the fillna() better.

Is there a code that lets me extract such rows?

I have 13 rows (loan_id, gender, married, credit_history, etc.)
Most of the rows do not have NaN values and my interest is in credit_history. How do I extract all rows have NaN values under credit history?

I'd like the output to be something similar to:

```
loan_id gender married credit_history loan_status
1         M      Y          NaN           Y
2         F      Y          NaN           N
3         M      Y          NaN           Y
4         M      Y          NaN           N
5         F      N          NaN           Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way:

```
df2 = df[pd.isnull(df['credit_history'])]
```

**Explanation**

- [`pd.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) creates a Boolean series in line with whether each entry in a series is `NaN`.
- You can then use this as an indexer for `df`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I'm still stuck as now I have too many rows with NaN values in credit_history and simply cannot take a decision visually.
What I'd like to know now is how do we get the value_counts() for all the non-numerical rows with credit_history as NaN?
Ideal output (non-numerical rows):
`Self_Employed
No     582
Yes    32`

`Married
Yes    398
No      213`

etc....

And for the numerical rows I'd like to get the average or median for all columns when credit_history column has NaN values. 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There you go

```
df_null = df[df["credit_history"].isnull()]
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then let me know.